# HTML5 Column of Letters

Tags: html, canvas

I need my letters stored in a string with spaces between them to make a vertical column with the letters still upright. This needs to be done in a HTML5 Canvas and I have no idea where to start, any ideas?

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t2zw1szmjjhtm2t/Capture.JPG?dl=0]

Comment: At least can you draw or show any samples what you want. Its like "I want a sheep looks like a goat looks like a cow and so on". If your questions needs more time to understand then how can you expect someone to help you.

Comment: @Nepal12 I've edited my question to give you the details you need, I'd love for you to have another look.

Comment: @GameAlchemist I'm sorry but being a student and unable to find the answer myself so I turned to this site. Please feel free to leave an answer if you're so good at this.

Comment: Hint: The `context.fillText` draws text and it has 2 required parameters: the x,y coordinates where the text is to be drawn. Armed with this knowledge---**Go forth and learn more about html5 canvas**.

Comment: @GameAlchemist are you drunk? Read **[Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)** (the official SO view on giving answers to poor questions).

Comment: And welcome to SO! As you can see, it is a cheerful welcome-committee waiting for everyone here :) (it's that time of the month.. always, at least for some). Don't take it personal. Did you try using context with fillText() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps you need to do are as follows:

- Iterate each char of the string
- use fillText (or strokeText) to draw the char at the position you want
- Increment height for each char.

## Example

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),  // get context of canvas
    str = "H E L L O",
    char, i = 0, len = str.length,
    x = 10, y = 30, height = 24;

ctx.font = "bold 24px sans-serif"; // set a font for text

while(i < len) {
  char = str.substr(i++, 1);       // get a char from string at index i
  ctx.fillText(char, x, y);        // draw to canvas at (x, y)
  y += height;                     // increment y with height
}
```

```html
<canvas width=50 height=250></canvas>
```

Note that font-height is not the same as font size, so make a good guess for it (TextMetics is suppose to implement this (ascend+descend) but not all browsers are there yet).

Comment: It's only slightly on-topic to your answer, but it seems that many typographers use the Golden Ratio to calculate line-height from font-size. Here's one article I found useful about a modified Golden Ratio calculation: http://imarc.net/blog/750-using_the_golden_ratio_with_typography.

Comment: @markE yeah, golden ratio has always been important in classics as well as modern times, from buildings to print. It has a slightly different historic background for the size vs. height though. In the past when using moving types, the plate the letter was on was the "size". The letter itself could vary in height. This concept was brought into the digital world more or less successfully (this is also where the 72.272 dpi comes in) :)

Comment: ...And totally off topic, I'm taking a look at your `psd-reader` lib--it's awesome!